# Push data from csv to postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

There are 7 fields:
id - char
img - char
phone - char
date-date
gender-char
address_id - foreign key
user_id  - foreign key

I have written a script to load this in the postgres db, looks something like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(user="user",
                        password="data",
                        host="",
                        port="5432",
                        database="")
cur = conn.cursor()


def load_data_on_db():
    with open(r'C:\Users\Documents\user.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        #next(reader)  # Skip the header row.
        for row in reader:
            cur.execute(
                'INSERT INTO "CollectData_userdetails" VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',row)
        conn.commit()


load_data_on_db()
```

Throws an error

> ```
> 'INSERT INTO "CollectData_userdetails" VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',row)
> ```
>
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Is that not a duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344690/csv-data-into-postgresql-using-python

Comment: it didnot work for me... throws no error but nothing gets loaded to the db